# Replacement for deprecated function glLineWidth()

Tags: swift, opengl-es, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I need a property or a method allowing me to control **line's width**. Useful and simple function `glLineWidth()` is now deprecated:

```
func glLineWidth(_ width: GLfloat)
```

**What function can I use instead of a deprecated one**?

Here's a code for making a 3D line:

```
class func drawLine(vector vector1: SCNVector3,
                  toVector vector2: SCNVector3) -> SCNGeometry {

    let indices: [Int32] = [0, 1]
    let source = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: [vector1, vector2]
    let element = SCNGeometryElement(indices: indices, primitiveType: .line)
    let geometry = SCNGeometry(sources: [source], elements: [element])
    return geometry
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no replacement in OpenGL and this feature doesn't exist in Metal.